# What is a good strategy for testing UserControls?

Tags: c#, winforms

A UserControl cannot be dragged-dropped onto a winform.  Instead, I must compile the assembly add it to my toolbox, then I can drag it onto a Form.

Doing this toolbox approach just to test out a control and then "tweak" it repeatedly is quite cumbersome.

Right now, I plan to simply have this toolbox item pointing to a bin/debug assembly which will be repeatedly re-built.  I imagine this will come with it's own set of problems.

So what is a good strategy for testing UserControls?

Comment: If you add a winforms application project to the same solution, your user control will show up in the toolbox.

Comment: @Tamas Szelei - See the related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9178582/adding-a-user-control-from-solution-explorer-to-a-winform

Comment: I don't get it. So your problem is that you can't drag'n'drop from the solution explorer, only from the toolbox?

Comment: My problem is how to perform rapid application development and unit testing against a user control.

Comment: As I said, if you add another project and reference this one, you have what you want. It doesn't need to be done each time you change something (I think you don't even have to manually add it to the toolbox once you reference the project).

Comment: Erm... How do you unit test your ordinary Windows forms?

Comment: @Robert Harvey - I instantiate the Form object and call `formObj.ShowDialog()`.  This allows me to visually inspect the form and optionally test the UI components.

Comment: So programmatically add the UserControl to an empty form, and show that.  Forms (and user controls) are just code; add the control manually to a form, observe what code changes take place in the designer code, and emulate those.

Comment: @Robert Harvey - That worked.  I do not think this solution is known or obvious to everyone.  It certainly was not to me.  If you would like to post this as an answer (especially pointing out how it shows up in the toolbox auto-magically) I will mark it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comments, you state that you unit test your Windows forms by programmatically instantiating them and performing a visual inspection.  I don't normally associate such testing with "unit testing," as unit testing is normally accomplished without any kind of user confirmation of the results; i.e. it is *completely automated.*

Regardless, if you simply want to instantiate a User Control programmatically, just add the User Control to a Windows form using code, and then show that form in the usual manner.

The necessary code for adding your User Control to the form will be automatically code-generated by Visual Studio if you drag the User Control onto the new form (the new code will be in the `#region` marked *"Windows Forms Designer generated code"* of the `designer` file).  You can then copy-paste that code to an appropriate place, and execute it as part of your test.

Comment: You are correct.  I am abusing MSTEST a little bit.  I'm using it as a UI invoking tool to do some manual testing.  I should have clarified because that is an unusual thing to do.